# asp.net login page issue

Tags: .net, asp.net, authentication, security

Q:

The `login page` is the start point to any web site and the most important thing to authenticate the user.

When i begin to build any web application , i think a lot of time how to design a login page with flexible interface and so secure .

My question is:

---

- **Is** there any common advices, tips , a must to do list to take in consideration when i begin to build this special page:especially (the
  security issues)?best practice.
  i wanna general advices , cause,my DBMS my be `informix` or `mysql` or `sql server`.

Comment: I hope i get more detailed answer has many points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lot's of suggestions for authentication in general (including login page):

1. Don't build your own authentication scheme, use the built-in membership provider
2. Reduce session timeouts to a bare minimum (consider usability)
3. Disable sliding expiration (again, consider the usability aspect)
4. Load the login page and all subsequent page thereafter over HTTPS
5. Ensure cookies are set to require HTTPS
6. Disable cookieless authentication
7. Don't use a liberal path in the role manager cookie
8. Set strong criteria for the minimum password strength
9. Make sure auto-complete is off on the logon form

There's more detail and further ideas in [OWASP Top 10 for .NET developers part 3: Broken authentication and session management](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/07/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-3.html). Also try passing your web.config through [WCSA](http://www.wcanalyzer.com).

Answer (score 3):

It is best to use [ASP.NET 2.0 Membership and Roles Tutorial Series](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/05/07/ASP.NET-2.0-Membership-and-Roles-Tutorial-Series.aspx)

and check this as well [http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/introduction/security-basics-and-asp-net-support-cs)

Answer (score 2):

The login page should be served over HTTPS and POSTing the login credentials to an HTTPS action on the server.

Answer (score 2):

1. Encrypt the password in a way that cannot be retrieved which is one way cifer and when the user enter his username and password and click login, take his entered password and cifer it and compare it with the saved password.
2. Use stored procedures and don't use inline database query concatenation so that you don't face a sql injection.
3. Use HTTPS

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Login` control that come with VS.

Here are some links to get you started.

[Link 1](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/LoginControl07242008104351AM/LoginControl.aspx)
[Link 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the use of the non-standard (but widely adopted) `autocomplete` attribute on your username and password fields for additional security.

By the way, is it purely tips about the interface you are looking for, or are you interested in server-side issues too, e.g. use of password encryption, salts etc?

Comment: no not just a design issues, i ask about more secure login page which can't be hacked:)